# Why is my Network Map output not showing in my shiny App?

Tags: r, shiny, edges, visnetwork

What concerns me the most is that it isn't getting an error, but it's just not showing!
I gotta mention that I even printed each line in order to check the progress as it advanced and it all came out as it regularly does on the console. I'm guessing that it must be in the `output$visnetwork` function, but I just don't know.

```
# --------------------------------------- Global --------------------------------------- #

# Set working directory -> Ctrl+Shift+H & Open the app folder
setwd("~/Programación en R/Shiny app/Client dashboard app")

# --------------------- Initialize program --------------------- #

# Print in console: global script is beginning to run
print("global.R")


#--------------------------------------- User Interface ---------------------------------------#

# Tell user ui script is beginning to run
print("ui.R")

ui <- fluidPage( 
  theme = shinytheme("cerulean"), 

  navbarPage("Analysis",

             #--- Home Tab (Global View)
             tabPanel("Global View",
                      sidebarPanel(),
                      visNetworkOutput("network")
                      ), #tabPanel - Global View  

             tabPanel("",
                      ) #tabPanel - 

  ) #navbarPage
) #fluidPage
#--------------------------------------- Server ---------------------------------------#

# Tell user server script is beginning to run
print("server.R")

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Gathering important variables in one only data set
    twd <<- NULL

  observe({                                                         
    twd <- structure(c(0.0156521739130435, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00633484162895928, 
0, 0, 0.0137931034482759, 0.118245390972664, 0, 0.0121739130434783, 
0.141455437448896, 0.00131061598951507, 0, 0.00580720092915215, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0200445434298441, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.036046511627907, 
0, 0, 0.00180995475113122, 0, 0, 0.0334975369458128, 0.0216147488874762, 
0.0449197860962567, 0.00956521739130435, 0.0834014717906787, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0121739130434783, 0.080130825838103, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0217391304347826, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0623608017817372, 0, 0.00762873490146217, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.00930232558139535, 0.0511033681765389, 0, 0, 0, 0.044543429844098, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0582608695652174, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0122494432071269, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00245298446443173, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0624434389140271, 
0, 0, 0, 0.00190718372536554, 0, 0, 0.00654129190515127, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0594541910331384, 0, 0, 0, 0.00320855614973262, 0.0121739130434783, 
0.00163532297628782, 0, 0.0558139534883721, 0, 0, 0, 0.00584795321637427, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0709302325581395, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00190718372536554, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0262443438914027, 0, 0.0089086859688196, 
0, 0.0133502860775588, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0368722186904005, 
0, 0, 0, 0.072083879423329, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0217391304347826, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0126705653021442, 0, 0, 0.0108073744437381, 
0, 0.0165217391304348, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0222504767959313, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0235294117647059, 0, 0.0178173719376392, 
0, 0.00699300699300699, 0, 0, 0.0098119378577269, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0427807486631016, 0.00521739130434783, 0.0335241210139002, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00254291163382072, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.0488974113135187, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0488974113135187, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0182608695652174, 0.0122649223221586, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0128342245989305, 0, 0.00408830744071954, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0134228187919463, 0.0262443438914027, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0305149396058487, 0), .Dim = c(12L, 
25L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("demand_response", "utility_model", 
"real_time", "model_discloses", "utility_model_discloses", "power_supply", 
"control_system", "control_module", "intelligent_terminal", "management_system", 
"energy_consumption", "disaggregated_model", "control_method", 
"power_grid", "electric_energy", "intelligent_power", "electricity_consumption", 
"power_consumption", "control_unit", "communication_module", 
"random_access", "uplink_frequency", "intelligent_control", "mobile_terminal", 
"power_utilization")))
    topic_names <<- c("1", "2", "3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12")                         
  })

  # Network Map

  observe({
  # Preparing data with igraph library

    twd_num_col <- ncol(twd)
    cor_threshold <- .8
    twd_cor <- cor(twd[,1:twd_num_col], method = "pearson")
    twd_cor[ twd_cor < cor_threshold ] <- 0
    diag(twd_cor) <- 0
    graph <- graph.adjacency(twd_cor, weighted=TRUE, mode="lower")
    E(graph)$edge.width  <- E(graph)$weight
    V(graph)$group       <- apply(twd, 2, which.max)  #Max topic prob for colors
    V(graph)$betweenness <- betweenness(graph, v = V(graph), directed = F)
    V(graph)$degree      <- degree(graph, v = V(graph))

    # Fit data for visNetwork 
    nm_data <- toVisNetworkData(graph)
    nodes <- nm_data[[1]]
    edges <- nm_data[[2]]
    nodes <- nodes[nodes$degree != 0,]    # Bye topics that don't have a connection (degree = 0)
    nodes$group <- swap(nodes$group , 1:length(topic_names), topic_names) # Swap long real names
    nodes$label <- rep("")
  })

  output$network <- renderVisNetwork({
    # Graph
    set.seed(17);visNetwork(nodes, edges, main = "Relation between topics")  %>% 
      visOptions(highlightNearest = TRUE, selectedBy = "group") %>%
      visInteraction(dragNodes = FALSE) %>%
      visLegend(useGroups = TRUE, main = "Topic", ncol = 2)  %>%
      visNodes(shape = "dot",label = NULL) %>%
      visEdges(smooth = FALSE) %>%
      visIgraphLayout(randomSeed = 17)
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

And when I super assigned the data fit for visNetwork, it gave me this: `Warning: Error in <observer>: cannot change value of locked binding for 'edges'` but it's printing quit alright so I'm confused.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? If it;s not showing, definitely need to see the UI to make sure you have things correct and a full code to run also helps in the process.

Comment: Not sure if by this is what you call a reproducible example, but I just added the full code!

Comment: @MelaniaCB this is not a reproducible example because we don't have access to your data or to the code you call at the beginning of your script. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to see what a reproducible example is.

Comment: All I did was asign _nodes_ & _edges_ `as.data.frame( )` when creating, as well as in `visNetwork` one more time.